# Php access folder from file

Tags: php, directory, scandir

I want to access a folder from a .php file using `scandir();`!

This is my folder tree:

```
- public_html:
     - lua:
          - fld1:
               - myfile.php
               - works(folder)
```

The "fld1" directory contains the php file and the "works" folder(the requested one)

The php file and the folder are in the same location!

I tried to access it like this:

```
<?php
$dir = "works/";

// Sort in ascending order - this is default
$a = scandir($dir);

// Sort in descending order
$b = scandir($dir,1);

print_r($a);
?>
```

But nothing is printed on the page!

I also tried this:

`$dir = "/works/";`

or the full path:

`$dir = "/public_html/lua/fld1/works/";`

Comment: Try change directory to : `$dir = "./works/";`?

Comment: Where are you calling `scandir($dir)` from ? Is it from index.php ?

Comment: you can use `__DIR__` to get the path and then from there specify which directory you want to scan

Comment: I call scandir from myfile.php

Comment: Hasta Dhana this worked!

Comment: You could also use `$dir = dirname(__FILE__) . "/works/";` or if you're using PHP > 5.3 you could use `$dir = __DIR__ . "/works/";`

Answer (score 0):

Give the path correctly

Try this:

```
$dir    = '/works';
```

or

```
$dir    = './works';
```